# How do I use tf.Dataset to load data into multiple GPUs?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, data-pipeline

Currently, I'm passing the data into multiple GPUs using get_next(). Is there a better way to feed data into multiple GPU s?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [shard](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#shard) class method which is aimed for distributed training. This could be what you need.